# xmlNodeGetContent memory leak, how to fix it?

Tags: soap, libxml2, xmlnode

We have code which does parsing of SOAP xml, and we use xmlNodeGetContent api. In valgrind it shows that it leaking memory. What i found in some posts that we need to explicitly free the memory returned by xmlNodeGetContent. Can someone help me on how to do this for below recursive calls?

````
{
while(node)
{
if(XML_ELEMENT_NODE == node->type)
{
if(0 == strcmp( soapMsgHeader.c_str() ,(const char*)node->name ) )
{
xmlNode childNode=node->children;
while(childNode)
{
if( (XML_ELEMENT_NODE == childNode->type) && ( 0 == ( xmlChildElementCount(childNode) ) ) )
{
std::string name= (const char)childNode->name;
std::string value = (const char*)xmlNodeGetContent(childNode);
soapHeaderAttributes.insert(std::pair< std::string, std::string> (name,value) );
}
childNode=childNode->next;
}
}

        if(0 == strcmp(soapMsgMo.c_str(), (const char*)node->name))
        {
            getSoapMsgMoList(node);
        }

        if(0 == strcmp(soapMsgBody.c_str(), (const char*)node->name))
        {
            node = node->children;
            while(XML_ELEMENT_NODE != node->type)
            {
                node = node->next;
            }
            msgTypeVal = (char*)node->name;
            node = node->parent;
        }
    }
    getSoapMsgDetails(node->children);
    node = node->next;
}
}```

How to fix the memory leak?
````

Answer (score 0):

You have to free the C string returned from `xmlNodeGetContent` with `xmlFree` (which typically points to `free` from the C library).

```
xmlChar *content = xmlNodeGetContent(childNode);
std::string value = (const char *) content;
xmlFree(content);
```